# Extract from array of objects some properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I extract from an array of objects some properties like without for loop, with map or filter?

Example:

```
obj = [
 { 'cars' : 15, 'boats' : 1, 'smt' : 0 },
 { 'cars' : 25, 'boats' : 11, 'smt' : 0 }
]

extractFunction(obj, ['cars' , 'boats']) -> { 'cars' : [15,25], 'boats' : [1,11]}
```

Comment: `without for loop, with map or filter?`  What do you mean by this?

Comment: Try using `.reduce()`, since your're 'reducing' an array of multiple objects into a summary of one object.

Comment: and why -4? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: @Grigor because Nina downvotes everyone that doesn't add what they've tried already.

Comment: what? I don't get it, please simple

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

* *As you can see, the benefit of this approach (according to the other answers) is that you loop the `keys` only one time.*

```js
const extractFunction = (items, keys) => {
  return items.reduce((a, value) => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
      // Before pushing items to the key, make sure the key exist
      if (! a[key]) a[key] = []
      
      a[key].push(value[key])
    })
    
    return a
  }, {} )
}

obj = [
 { 'cars' : 15, 'boats' : 1, 'smt' : 0 },
 { 'cars' : 25, 'boats' : 11, 'smt' : 0 }
]

console.log(extractFunction(obj, ['cars', 'boats']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a dynamic approach by using the keys for mapping the values.

```js
function extractFunction(array, keys) {
    return array.reduce(
        (r, o) => (keys.forEach(k => r[k].push(o[k])), r),
        Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: [] })))
    );
}

console.log(extractFunction([{ cars: 15, boats: 1, smt: 0 }, { cars: 25, boats: 11, smt: 0 }], ['cars', 'boats']));
```